# Android GridView pinch zoom

Tags: android, gridview, zooming, pinch

I'm trying to implement the pinch gesture to zoom in/ zoom out of a GridView in Android.
I've been searching the web for a while now and I've found multiple answers but it comes down to creating a custom GridView and set a gesturelistener to this GridView.
But I can't find any examples or tutorials on how to do this.

So I am really looking for an example or something to send me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try look at https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView library. Not GridView, but I thing that the basics are the same.